# Problem accessing 10.0 File Geodatabase from ArcGIS Desktop 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, file-geodatabase

I'm on 10.0 SP4 (build 4000) and two co-workers are on 10.1 original release (build 3035 I believe). The DB was provided by a client and saved on a network drive. Since I have no issue accessing the data I assumed it was created in 10.0 or earlier. One of the co-workers is trying to access the data remotely, the other from within the office network. They both got the same "Failed to connect to database" error message. A third co-worker on 10.0 gave it a try in the office and it worked for him.

This looks to me a typical backward compatibility scenario, plus there are other DBs created in 10.0 and they had no issue accessing from 10.1. I'm puzzled why this is happening? Shapefiles were created so everyone can reference the data, but I'm really curious in finding out what could be the cause of the issue.

Comment: I've seen this happening a couple of times when storing a file geodatabase on a network drive. Maybe some utility was run on a network drive or the network connection error occurred at that time. The way I fixed that once is by creating a new file geodatabase and copying all the contents into this gdb.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll try your workaround if this happens again. Good to know that I'm not the only one!